# How can I count the occurrences of an item in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries (abbreviated).

```
my_list = [{ 'id':1, 'val':123 }, {'id':2, 'val':456 }, {'id':2, 'val':789 }]
```

How can I count the occurrences of dictionaries with a specified value for a particular key (in this case '`id`')?  Is there a way to leverage count (`my_list.count('id' = 1)` ?!?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
sum(1 for d in my_list if d.get('id') == the_value_you_are_interested_in)

>>> my_list = [{ 'id':1, 'val':123 }, {'id':2, 'val':456 }, {'id':2, 'val':789 }]
>>> sum(1 for d in my_list if d.get('id') == 1)
1
>>> sum(1 for d in my_list if d.get('id') == 2)
2
>>> sum(1 for d in my_list if d.get('id') == 20)
0
```

Note the use of the *generator* rather than a *list* of 1s.  This is a pretty established technique and probably appears on several Stack Overflow questions.

I don't see any way to leverage `list.count(x)` since this method counts the number of occurrences of `x`, which in your case would be complete dictionaries.  Python does have a `filter` method, but comprehensions are much preferred.

Comment: I do not understand your message in last line in answer - python learner.

Comment: If I write `sum([1 for x in a])` and `a` is a huge list, then the list comprehension theoretically generates a huge list of 1s, THEN sums them all up.  But if I write `sum(1 for x in a)` then the 1s are summed as `a` is being iterated on, without the large structure being realized.

Comment: Got It now! very useful information for me. Thanks you very much.

Comment: One more thing you says "compression are preferred over `filter()`" but I read in Apress-Beginning that filter, map, reduction are much faster than list-compressions.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Much faster?  I don't think so.  Map+filter might sometimes be faster than a comprehension, but not by much.  If you have a large list use a generator instead of a comprehension in case a lazy map is the thing that is "much faster".  See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: Ok Got it, filter, map, reduction are slightly faster but list list-comprehensions  are better readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I like @Ray's answer. Another cool trick is to use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter( item for dct in my_list for item in dct.items() )
c
=> Counter({('id', 2): 2, ('val', 123): 1, ('id', 1): 1, ('val', 456): 1, ('val', 789): 1})

c[('id', 2)]
=> 2
c[('id', 1)]
=> 1
c[('id', 20)]
=> 0
```

This solution is particularly good if you need to count multiple keys/values.

If you only care about a particular key, you can do:

```
k = 'id'
id_counter = Counter( dct.get(k) for dct in my_list )
id_counter
=> Counter({2: 2, 1: 1})
id_counter[2]
=> 2
```